# Is there a right way to connect to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, go

I've come across documentation that says:

> the sql.DB object is designed to be long-lived. Don’t Open() and
>   Close() databases frequently. Instead, create one sql.DB object for
>   each distinct datastore you need to access

[source](http://go-database-sql.org/accessing.html)

And doing some poking around I mostly found code opening the connection in the handler file as so

```
func dbConn() (db *sql.DB) {
  dbDriver := "mysql"
  dbUser := "root"
  dbPass := "root"
  dbName := "goblog"
  db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbUser+":"+dbPass+"@/"+dbName)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }
  return db
}
```

[source](https://www.golangprograms.com/example-of-golang-crud-using-mysql-from-scratch.html)

And to access the db

```
 db := dbConn()
```

This is called in the functions that need to use it, to my understanding this would open the connection and then close it when it reaches the end of said function.

Wouldn't this be violating the quote above?

Comment: This function only opens connection and returns `*sql.DB`. It does not closes connection. Nothing is violated here

Comment: Ok, so would that mean every time a function calls it a new connection is made?

Comment: Ah! It could be more complicated because driver can do connection pooling. But anyway - it's not a good idea to rely on connection pooling. General recommendation - try to reuse existing connections.

Comment: The proper source to consult is always the official documentation and yes, the violate what package database/sql says. (Random tutorials on the internet are, well, just random tutorials.)

Comment: Yes, that violates the principle in the documentation. `sql.Open` should typically be called once per application (there are exceptions, of course).

Comment: @AlexYu Please explain the difference between relying on connection pooling and trying to reuse existing connections,

Comment: @user207421 Sorry. I see I was not clear enough. There are two types of connection pools: client-side (usual and regulated by db driver) and server-side (vendor-specific, more rare). In "don't rely on connection pool" I meant: "don't rely that somebody will cure your code on server-side"

Answer (score 2):

The example is simply poorly written, and Yes you shouldn't `Open` and `Close` unless its different datastores.

`Open` returns `DB` and

> DB is a database handle representing a pool of zero or more underlying connections. It's safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines